# Possible to store CoreData objects to the app itself, and not on the device?

Tags: ios

I use CoreData in my app, and I thought the objects I have uploaded gets saved to the app itself, and not just the device. I stored all my objects on the iPhone 5s simulator on Xcode, and those objects gets retrieved successfully when I use that simulator. But if I switch simulator or use my own device, it says I have 0 objects.

Is there any work arounds here? Or do I have to make every user upload the necessary objects "themselves" ?

This is my code for retrieving my objects:

```
 //1
        let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

        //2
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Persons")

        //3
        do {
            let results =
            try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            GameData.data.people = results as! [NSManagedObject]



        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
```

Comment: Why do you want to have shared coredata?

Comment: I have got around 3000 objects I need in my game. I won't be saving any objects, all I will do is retrieve the 3000 needed objects.

Comment: there can't be any workarounds, it's nonsense. of course each user must upload/download necessary objects themselves.

Comment: I used to use CloudKit to retrieve my objects, but it took about 15 seconds to fully retrieve all objects. It was not that big of a deal, but seeing as it takes no time retrieving them using CoreData, I thought I should switch to core data. But if there really is no work around, I will most likely have to switch back to CloudKit

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you think "saved to the app itself" would mean. You can include a persistent store full of Core Data objects as part of your app bundle. As part of the bundle that data is available on every installation and read only but you could copy it to an appropriate location to create an editable store. You'll also have to consider how app updates should or should not replace this data in a new version.

Comment: All I want is that every user will be able to retrieve my stored objects. As mentioned earlier, I won't be saving any objects. I may have to edit my objects once a year tough, as a part of an update. What you propose sounds interesting, but I know very little of the subject. How do I include a persistent store full of Core Data objects a part of my app bundle? Do I have to make any modifications in the code I used when uploading the objects? Thanks for answering BTW